# How to move and resize the dynamic textbox in wpf

Tags: dynamic, textbox, resize

I created multiple texboxes with button click

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        i = i + 150;
        j = j + 250;
        TextBox x = new TextBox();
        x.Name = "new_textbox";
        x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        x.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        x.AcceptsReturn = true;
        x.Width = 200;
        x.Height = 200;
        x.Margin = new Thickness(i, j, j, j);
        x.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(tboxMouseMove);
        can.Children.Add(x);
    }
```

private void tboxMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
            // here we have pass the textbox object so that we can use its all property on necessary
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tb, tb, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

But not able to move this dynamic textbox using the above code. please correct the code to resize and move the textbox

Answer (score 0):

You will need a class for moving and resizing the control.

[visit this link for further assistance.](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/74178/How-to-resize-and-move-dynamically-created-textbox)